# Returning control to switch statement in java?

Tags: java, loops

I have a client-server console based application, in client side I have used switch statement for selecting options such as upload/ download/ change password etc. When user enters one number for suppose

```
      String userchoice = console.readLine("Enter your choice :"); 
      int choice= Integer.parseInt(userchoice);
      switch (choice){  
      case 3: 
      ........
      Socket soc = new Socket("localhost", 6007);
      String reply;
      String client = username;
      char newpswd[] = console.readPassword("Enter your new Password :");
      String newpwd=new String(newpswd);
      char newpswd1[] = console.readPassword("Confirm your new Password :");
      String newpwd1=new String(newpswd1);
      if(newpwd.equals(newpwd1)) {
      ........
      }
      else {
      S.O.P ("Passwords don't match");  
      }
      break;
```

After the process has been finished, then I need to send the user to switch (choice) statement again asking for the option number to enter. I have tried **continue**, **return** but none worked for me. **return** - will return to JVM I suppose, which is exiting the program. As goto is not used in Java, what will be my alternative ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> After the process has been finished, then I need to send the user to switch (choice) statement again

Then you need a loop:

```
while (!quit) {
    String userchoice = console.readLine("Enter your choice :"); 
    ...
    switch (...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
do {

...

}while(choice != EXIT_CHOICE);
```

where EXIT_CHOICE is a constant

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop, which will execute until it's condition is false or until it is broken from within.

```
while (some condition) {
    String userchoice = console.readLine("Enter your choice :");
    ......
    if (some case is met) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put it all in a method that returns a boolean, true if the passwords matched, false if not. Then you could use something like:

```
boolean loginSuccess = false;
while (!loginSuccess) {
    loginSuccess = loginMethod();
}
```

**Edit**

Or you could use a do loop...

```
do {
    String userchoice = console.readLine("Enter your choice :"); 
    int choice= Integer.parseInt(userchoice);
    switch (choice){  
    case 3: 
    ........
    Socket soc = new Socket("localhost", 6007);
    String reply;
    String client = username;
    char newpswd[] = console.readPassword("Enter your new Password :");
    String newpwd=new String(newpswd);
    char newpswd1[] = console.readPassword("Confirm your new Password :");
    String newpwd1=new String(newpswd1);
} while (!newpwd.equals(newpwd1));
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work this way. When you get to a switch, it decides (based in the expression evaluated, and the choices present) which will be the next op to be executed, and does nothing more (that is why you need the `break` statement to avoid running into the next bunch of code).

Get the switch into a loop or a function that gets called twice.